# How to get JTextField name in which is Document placed?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener

Is there something like event.getSource for DocumentListener too? 
Im trying to change color of just one JTextField in which is text changing.
Here is my DocumentListener:

```
DocumentListener posluchac = new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            warn(e);
        }
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            warn(e);
        }
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            warn(e);
        }
        public void warn(DocumentEvent e) {
            txtName.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            txtSurname.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            txtPersonalNumber.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            txtDateOfBirth.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    };
```

If there is nothing like `.getSource()` for DocumentListener. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, there is no `getSource()` like some other listeners but you can use Document class's `putProperty()` and `getProperty()` to achieve what you are looking for.

you can do

```
JTextField jTextField = new JTextField("Text 1");
jTextField.getDocument().putProperty("parent", jTextField);
```

and

later in DocumentListener's events, you can get the parent like this

```
JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getDocument().getProperty("parent");
```

where e is `DocumentEvent`

Comment: I had to use putProperty instead of setProperty. Your reply helped me a lot. Thank you kind sir.