# Get Element name in DocumentEvent

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener

Is it possible to get the root elements name, actionCommand, etc... in DocumentListener. I need to get the JTextField name to keep a track of which textfield was modified.

```
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    //something like this
    e.getName() //helps to keep a track which textfield was modified
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html), the only interesting things you can get is the type of that event **and** the `document that sourced the changed event`. Maybe digging in the `getDocument()` method could help you.

Comment: Yes, came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774732/how-to-get-jtextfield-name-in-which-is-document-placed

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Document is just model. The same document can be set in multiple JTextComponents.